# How to pass value into Listener in selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have 2 dropdowns: Type & Code. I want the Code dropdown to change values depending on the Type dropdown if value = A or B or C. How can I pass value of A or B or C into listener so it can understand and process my List ?

```
     <h:outputLabel value="Type" for="idType" />
     <h:selectOneMenu id="idType" value="#{myController.type}">
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="AAA" itemValue="AAA" />
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="BBB" itemValue="BBB" />
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="CCC" itemValue="CCC" />
         <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{myController.changeCodeList}" render="idCode" execute="@this" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
     <h:outputLabel value="Code" for="idCode" />
     <h:selectOneMenu id="idCode" value="#{myController.code}" >
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ..." noSelectionOption="true" />
         <f:selectItems value="#{myController.codeList}" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Ajax4jsf is a sublibrary of RichFaces with tags of the `<a4j:xxx>` library. You don't seem to be using it anywhere. Please do not use the `[ajax4jsf]` tag on your question then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove the `event="valueChange"` from your `<f:ajax` or replace it with `event="change"`

You don't have to pass the value as its already there (in `changeCodeList` method)

```
public void changeCodeList(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
    System.out.println(type); //here is your value
    //now repopulate your list based on the value
    codeList = someMethod(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="You want to pass" target="Backing bean property that you want to set" />
```

n another option is

```
<a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" reRender="codeCombo"
                            event="onchange"></a4j:support>
```

so using a4j:support you can rerender code on the selection  of type

Comment: Thanks for yor reply, I will check it. Maybe richface4 does not support a4j:support, I can't see that element