# change event doesn't work in selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have 2 dropdown lists: Country & State. I want to reload the state list when change the selection of the country list. 
I tried the [How to pass value into Listener in selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244620/how-to-pass-value-into-listener-in-selectonemenu).
However, the change event in my code doesn't work. Could anyone can help me? Thank you.

[image: Country & State dropdowns]

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="ddlCountry" value="#{Bean.companyCountry}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country.value}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{Bean.loadStates}" render="ddlState" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="ddlState" value="#{Bean.companyState}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.states}" var="state" itemValue="#{state.value}" itemLabel="#{state.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Java Bean class [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

```
private ArrayList<State> states;
public ArrayList<State> getStates() {
    return states;
}
public void loadStates(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    states = new ArrayList<State>();
    if(companyCountry.equals("USA")){
        states.add(new State("1","UT"));
        states.add(new State("2","WA"));
        states.add(new State("3","CA"));
    }
}
```

---

The jsf ajax listener still cannot work in my project. So I used primefaces tag, and it can solve my problem.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="ddlCountry" value="#{Bean.companyCountry}"  >
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country.value}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="ddlState" process="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="ddlState" value="#{Bean.companyState}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.states}" var="state" itemValue="#{state.value}" itemLabel="#{state.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Java Bean class [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

```
private ArrayList<State> states;
public ArrayList<State> getStates() {
    states = new ArrayList<State>();
    if(companyCountry.equals("USA")){
        states.add(new State("1","UT"));
        states.add(new State("2","WA"));
        states.add(new State("3","CA"));
    }
    else{
        states.clear();
    }
    return states;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `form` around your first `selectOneMenu` ?

Comment: `h:form`? also what scope is your bean?

Comment: try making it `@ViewScoped` instead

Comment: @Daniel I used ViewScoped instead.But the state list is still blank.

Comment: does your listener being called ? are you sure that the list being populated ? you sure about the condition is being `true` ? `if(country.name.equals("USA")){`

Comment: @Daniel I think you are right. I'll check it.

Comment: b.t.w try it with `@RequestScoped` and `<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{accountRegistrationBean.loadStates}" render="yourFormId ddlState"/>` (added `yourFormId` to render...)

Answer (score 0):

Change your bean scope from `@RequestScoped` to `@ViewScoped`

Otherwise right after you invoke the `listener` method , a new instance of the bean will be created , and your other `h:selectOneMenu` will be populated with empty values

Comment: Thank you for your help. Because it's in a big project, I'll make a simple demo to check it.